# Select id and matching username order?

Tags: php, mysqli

How do you know if `$id1` matches the row of `$user1` or `$user2`? Is this the correct way to do this query?

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user1',username='$user2' LIMIT 2";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$id1 = $row[0];
$id2 = $row[1];
```

- can I use `ORDER BY username='$user1'` ?

Comment: Firstly, your query's syntax is invalid. RTMs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in comments, your syntax is invalid. A `WHERE` clause uses `AND` or `OR` as separators, not commas.

So what you need to do here, is adjust your query and compare them thereafter:

*Sidenote:* You may need to add extra columns to the SELECT as that may throw you an undefined offset notice. Also make sure that if you have more than 2 rows, your LIMIT of 2 may fail on you.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user1' OR username='$user2' LIMIT 2";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$id1 = $row[0];
$id2 = $row[1];

if($user1 == $id1) {

    echo "User 1 is the same ";

}

if($user2 == $id2) {

    echo "User 2 is the same";

}
```

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html

As per your edit:

> *can I use ORDER BY username='$user1'*

No, you need to use `ORDER by column_name`, and not an "equal to" and a variable.

If your column name is the same as the variable, then that is possible but I won't know that for sure until your db schema / contents are known.

The syntax is:

`ORDER BY column` accepts `ASC` or `DESC` depending on the order you want.

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

---

If your query has any user intervention/input, you will need to use a prepared statement, since that would leave you open to an SQL injection.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: but there's no duplicates of username so it couldn't select something that matches $user1 AND $user2

Comment: @stkmedia I'm confused then. You need to post your db schema and an example of what your output should be.

Comment: @stkmedia I edited, using an `OR` rather than `AND`. Is that what you're looking for? I also need to know about the above comment.

Comment: @stkmedia Hold on... I think I may know what the query should be. Give me a minute, I'll edit.

Comment: @stkmedia I had to rollback your question to a previous edit. You can't go editing your question "on the fly" with what the proper syntax should have been. I added what you asked was correct on how to ORDER BY and have made an edit to that effect, including a new query. Again, we/I need to know what your db contains for values and what those variables values are. I can't go editing back and forth like this and guessing what you're looking for a solution.

Comment: @stkmedia It's ok, you may not have known. Glad to hear that I was able to have provided a solution for you. Btw, I made another edit to my answer. You will need to reload it and look above the code/query under *Sidenote:*. There are some important notes you will need to know about. Errors came up for me while testing, since I did not know what your db schema was. So I had to improvise.